# Perfomance Effect of Laravel Framework

Tags: php, laravel, symfony

I'm wondering about the performance implications of using the laravel framework.  Mainly the disk seeks, if it's scalable and if I can somehow cache the files in RAM.

Thanks!

Comment: Same question can also be answered about symfony.

Comment: This is not really a question for SO, but yes of course you can cache in RAM you can cache any PHP app in RAM using memcache or redis. Performance depends on the situation, if you need high performance, low latency, high request per second then PHP is probably not the correct choice

Comment: Cache what files in RAM? PHP code itself? Use OpCache! Otherwise use Laravel's Caching system

Comment: Very broad question and useless without any specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything depands on which technologies you're using. If we're talking about the *cache* system Laravel's provides few popular cache drivers such as *Memcache* or *Redis* but you're also free to write your own one and conect it with Laravel `Cache` facade.

If you need to have fast raquests and memory-saving way of creating web app you should read about [Lumen](https://lumen.laravel.com/) (Laravel's micro-framework).

All other implications (as I wrote at the begining) depands on what technology and programming technique You'll choose to your solution.

**I.E.:**

If  you're app is based on large data sets from the database - which has to be processed - then it's better to not using *Eloquent's* `Model`. Instead of it the technique is to us plain Laravel's `DB` facade (database controller wrapper).